# Kendo UI Client Side Validation erros as list

Tags: kendo-ui

I am using Kendo UI ASP.Net MVC framework and I have a kendo grid one of our pages. I am able do client side validation when the grid is in edit mode(using in-line editing). Any error messages are displayed next to the field, it is possible to get all these errors and display them as a list when the Update button is clicked on the row.

Answer (score 1):

No, such validation summary is not supported, however you can customize where the messages are shown like explained [here](http://www.kendoui.com/forums/kendo-ui-framework/validation/validation-messages-position.aspx).